# Balance Loading - ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, load-balancing

A friend has an ASP.NET application used for student registration. Around 200 concurrent users are using the application.

Out of a sudden every some time the CPU reaches 100% usage. The Server has 8 GB ram, however only 3 or 4 are being used.

He decided to upgrade to 10 CPUs, every now and then, around 8 CPUs drop to 0 or 5 % only, and only 1 or 2 CPUs will be functioning with 100% and hence they go and restart IIS to fix the problem.

What are the options I could look at to help resolve this issue?

Much appreciated.

Comment: is your friend using a  static dictionary?

Comment: You are too generic. What is the app doing and what does the profiler tell you? do you have a FAT app or can you split services, bl and DAL to another app pool or app server?

Comment: Can't you find any suitable answer? http://www.google.com.tr/#sclient=psy-ab&q=iis+load+balancing+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ahmet Kakıcı: that is not necessarily the actual problem...

Answer (score 0):

There are several coding reasons why this could happen:

- [High CPU in .NET app using a static Generic.Dictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Case Study: High CPU in GC - Large objects and high allocation rates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/06/22/asp-net-case-study-high-cpu-in-gc-large-objects-and-high-allocation-rates.aspx)